# Files associated with Thunderbird - Security mechanism for local storage

Tags: email, security, imap, thunderbird

I am trying to know how Thunderbird stores the mails, associated files in the local machine.

I use **Ubuntu 13.10** and **Thunderbird 24.6.0**

When I see in the local profile folder in the location in ~/.thunderbird , there exists a profile folder say . For my experiments, I listed the files inside that folder **WITHOUT OPENING the THUNDERBIRD**, and then listed again after  **I opened the Thunderbird**

Here is what I found:

- Among the files, a file called **session.json** will be there in the
  folder, when thunderbird is not open. (It will vanish when I open
  Thunderbird)
- When Thunderbird is opened, as told earlier, session.json will
  vanish and the below files will appear.

  - lrwxrwxrwx 1 sid sid       16 okt    6 13:41 **lock ->** 127.0.1.1:+13149
  - -rw-r--r-- 1 sid sid        0 okt    6 13:41 **cookies.sqlite-wal**
  - -rw-r--r-- 1 sid sid    32768 okt    6 13:41 **cookies.sqlite-shm**
  - -rw-r--r-- 1 sid sid        0 okt    6 13:41 **webappsstore.sqlite-wal**
  - -rw-r--r-- 1 sid sid    32768 okt    6 13:41 **webappsstore.sqlite-shm**
  - -rw-r--r-- 1 sid sid        0 okt    6 13:41 **places.sqlite-wal**
  - -rw-r--r-- 1 sid sid    32768 okt    6 13:41 **places.sqlite-shm**
  - -rw-r--r-- 1 sid sid   721584 okt    6 13:41 **global-messages-db.sqlite-journal**

***I want to know what are the significance of these files.***

Also, I tried to change the **INBOX** file of both IMAP and POP folders( keeping my Thunderbird closed), expecting the changes I made ( say I added some line in some particular mail) will appear in the thunderbird client. (Of course the computer was connected to Internet). But I could see no change.

1. **What is preventing me from seeing those changes in the thunderbird
   mail client?**
2. **If I want to see the changes, how can I do it?**

Any help to make my understanding better will be much much appreciated.

Comment: Those are sqlite journal files: wal is write ahead log, shm is a shared memory index, and journal is a journal file.

Comment: @Max Thanks Max, but what is preventing from seeing the changes made to INBOX file in the THunderBird mail client.

Comment: Presumably, when it downloads messages, it adds them to the sqlite databases as it writes them out to the filesystem. Since you put them in out of band, it did not update the databases and did not see them.

Comment: @Max So there is no way that I see those changes?

Answer (score 0):

Those files are storage that the implementation of different technologies use to store things on disk.

- cookies: web cookies
- webappsstore: html5 localstorage and such
- places: browser history
- global-messages-db: index for thunderbird's global message indexer

The POP Inbox file can be edited when the application is disconnected and changes will show up.

IMAP Inbox is normally read from the server. If you put thunderbird into offline mode, changes would show up.

Comment: I edited the INBOX file when Thunderbird client was not open, But when I open the Thunderbird file, the changes I made wont show up. I am using POP account settings.

Comment: You must be editing the wrong file, or editing just some part that's not used in display. Try editing e.g. a subject of a known mail to start with.